# Преобразование Map в класс помеченный Java аннотациями

Tags: java, аннотации

Добрый день! Имеются следующие аннотации:

**@Dictionary**

```
@Target(value = ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(value= RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Dictionary {
   String value();
}
```

**@DictionaryAttribute**

```
@Target(value= ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(value= RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface DictionaryAttribute {
    String value();
}
```

Создан класс `ExampleClass`, в котором используются данные аннотации:

```
@Dictionary(value = "eu_department")
public class ExampleClass {

    @DictionaryAttribute(value = "code")
    String code;

    @DictionaryAttribute(value = "name")
    String value;

    /**
     * getters / setters
     */

}
```

Каким образом можно преобразовать `Map<String, String>` со следующими данными в `ExampleClass`?

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("code", "123");
map.put("name", "Привет");
```

Comment: добавлю замечание небольшое, по логике из Map странно получать один экземпляр ExampleClass, скорее всего список из таких экземплляров

Answer (score 2):

Можно как-то так, например:

```
public static void writeDictionary(Object obj, Map<String, ?> map)
        throws SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    for (Field field : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        DictionaryAttribute attr = field.getAnnotation(DictionaryAttribute.class);
        if (attr != null) {
            String keyName = attr.value();
            if (map.containsKey(keyName)) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                field.set(obj, map.get(keyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Аннотация `@Dictionary` как будто бы не нужна. Заметьте, что я пишу напрямую в поля, используя `setAccessible(true)`, потому что в целом неочевидно, что соответствующий сеттер как-то связан с полем. Если хочется писать через сеттеры (к примеру, у вас `SecurityManager` запрещает манипулировать правами доступа), по-моему, лучше аннотировать сеттеры, а не поля. Формировать имя сеттера по имени поля (типа `"set"+field.getName().substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+field.getName().substring(1)`) ненадёжно: никто не гарантирует, что это всегда сработает.

Пример использования:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("code", "123");
map.put("name", "Привет");

ExampleClass obj = new ExampleClass();
writeDictionary(obj, map);
```

Если вы хотите, чтобы и объект сам создавался с помощью конструктора по умолчанию, можно добавить такой метод:

```
public static <T> T fromDictionary(Class<T> targetClass, Map<String, ?> map)
        throws SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
        InstantiationException {
    T obj = targetClass.newInstance();
    writeDictionary(obj, map);
    return obj;
}
```

Использование:

```
ExampleClass obj = fromDictionary(ExampleClass.class, map);
```